# Is it possible to sign in to my website and use the e-mail and password to authenticate on power bi?

Tags: api, authentication, powerbi

I have a website and I want to put power bi dashboards for clients. I want use an `iframe` tag with power bi authentication (secure embed code),. However, if I use this technique the client has to sign in on the power bi website and my website. I would like that the client sign in to website and use the account and password to request a login on power bi with an API. Is this possible? If so, how can I do this? Which API do I have to use?

I saw [this example](https://radacad.com/sharing-power-bi-reports-with-secure-embed-code).

```html
<!-- iframe example -->
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="..." frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is called **"App owns data"**. You can find full instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers).

The other solution would be to [**publish to web**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web) and then embedding the code in your website. Please notice that this is **public** sharing and everyone who will get hold of the link will be able to access your reports.